# Detect line of white pixels on image in Objective-c (Cocoa)

Tags: c++, objective-c, image-processing

I'm building a app that uses images from a webservice. Unfortunatly the images are padded with white (when the service resized them, long time ago).

I want to make a class that detects if the image has complete lines, horizontal or vertical, of the same white nuance, and then crop the image. (or remove the white area)

So basically i'm thinking:
- Run through the horizontal lines (full width and 1 px height) and check if it has the same white nuance all across.

(To optimize later i could detect the color by detectiong firsk and last pixel and if they matches then check half way etc.) - Not important in first draft.

Regarding the padding, i cant be sure about the size of the padding. The images is in various sizes and proportions and padded to be the same size. So the padded borders changes from image to image.

**EDIT:**
Here is one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/37//74438337_30052011063215_9539_3.jpg and a vertical one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/40//74273140_23052011090107_0806_3.jpg and a tricky one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/61/500396561_27052011171605_5877_3.jpg note that the last has partly white background, why i need to detect if the white-ish pixels goes all across the image width.

Could yo please give me a code example to get started. The hard part, i think, is to run trough the image pixel-wise and detect the color.

Maybe C++ would be much faster to do his?

I'm capable of Both C++ and Objective-C so give me your best shot :-)

Comment: how varied is the image? Are you processing an image that has a fixed line of the same RGB white values without any skew?

Comment: Its padded with the same white color (ffffff og RGB:255,255,255) but jpeg compressed, so there can be som minor nuance changes, because of the compression.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you manage to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSImage* yourImage;
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[yourImage TIFFRepresentation]];

unsigned char* pixelData = [bitmapRep bitmapData];
```

The pixels are probably in RGB format, so from here it should be easy to traverse the image pixel by pixel.

You can check the data format:

```
int depth       = [bitmapRep bitsPerSample];
int channels    = [bitmapRep samplesPerPixel];
int height      = [bitmapRep size].height;
int width       = [bitmapRep size].width;
```

**EDIT**: In order to verify Wajih's claims I wrote a little (quick & dirty) test program, I need some help to determine the border with the Hough transform though:

**EDIT2**: I realized that Wajih was referring to a special Hough transform (kht) implementation (not the OpenCV version), I have no time measurement for the kht. I updated the source code to handle jpg compression artefacts.

```
std::string origFileName("../data/500396561_27052011171605_5877_3.jpg");
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(origFileName, 0);

std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " -- widht, height = " << image.cols << ", " << image.rows << std::endl;

QElapsedTimer naiveTimer;
naiveTimer.start();
unsigned int x1 = 0;
unsigned int y1 = 0;
unsigned int x2 = 0;
unsigned int y2 = 0;

const unsigned int thresholdColor = 15; // how much may the color deviate
const unsigned int thresholdPixel = 5;  // how many false detections do you want to tolerate

for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < 1000; ++ii)
{
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;
    unsigned char* pixel = image.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
    unsigned char border = *pixel;
    bool top = true;

    // horizontal border lines
    for (int yy = 0; yy < image.rows; ++yy)
    {
        pixel = image.ptr<unsigned char>(yy);
        int count = 0;
        for (int xx = 0; xx < image.cols; ++xx)
        {
            if (255 - *pixel < thresholdColor)
                ++count;

            ++pixel;
        }
        if (image.cols - count < thresholdPixel)
        {
            if (top) ++y1;
            else ++y2;
        }
        else top = false;
    }
    y2 = image.rows - y2;


    // vertical border lines
    bool left = true;
    pixel = image.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
    unsigned int offset = image.ptr<unsigned char>(1) - pixel;
    for (int xx = 0; xx < image.cols; ++xx)
    {
        int count = 0;
        unsigned char* colPixel = pixel++;
        for (int yy = 0; yy < image.rows; ++yy)
        {
            if (255 - *colPixel < thresholdColor)
                ++count;

            colPixel += offset;
        }
        if (image.rows - count < thresholdPixel)
        {
            if (left) ++x1;
            else ++x2;
        }
        else left = false;
    }
    x2 = image.cols - x2;
}

std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " -- Time elapsed: " << naiveTimer.elapsed() << std::endl;
std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " -- x1 y1 x2 y2: " << x1 << " " << y1 << " " << x2 << " " << y2 << std::endl;

QImage original(origFileName.c_str());
QImage cropped = original.copy(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

EHVhu.jpg (the image that I used for testing, besides the images provided by esbenr):
[image: The image that I used for testing]

Comment: Awesome man. In my head this really was way more complicated. Thanks for clearing things up. I'll try it out Monday back at work. If I can get to the bottom of it, I'll definitely post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to adopt a better and faster algorithm. You can use Hough transform algorithms to detect lines. here you can even set the width and the length of the lines to be detected. This link might be useful [Here](http://www.ic.uff.br/~laffernandes/projects/kht/index.html).
 If you have any experience of OpenCV, you can use its built in fast methods to do a hough transform line detection. Probably you should check first if it is portable to Cocoa.

Comment: You suggest that the poster needs to adapt a "faster algorithm" and then suggest a Hough transform  for a problem that can probably be faster solved by two for loops and a handful of variables.

Comment: @bjoernz, Hough transform is a faster way of tackling the problem that the poster has at hand. Hough transform transforms the problem space in a more compact domain. Thats why its faster. The "two" loops approach could possibly be fast if its a icon size image to be processed. For larger images Hough transform is better. Probably I should have mentioned this in my original answer. Probably you did not know this too.

Comment: @Wajih but the transform itself is more expensive than tackling the problem directly. If I understand the problem correctly he just wants to crop the image in case a previous resize operation added a white border.

Comment: @bjoernz, Well if the problem is fixed, say borders appear only on a specific part of the image for all images, and fixed size of one pixel, then yes the two loop approach might be fast as already we know where the borders will appear. But if that is not the case, than traversing the whole is expensive, and BELIEVE me hough transform is faster and is been tested for this very purpose as far as I know. Unless I have missed something about it. Sure transform is a bit expensive. But not more than the loopy approach, based on certain conditions that is.

Comment: @Wajih you have got the issue correct. Whether i should use a transform or the loopy-approach - that's exactly why i asked the question here. Regarding the padding, i cant be sure about the size of the padding. The images is in various sizes and proportions and padded to be the same size. So the padded borders changes from image to image.

Comment: @esbenr, well good to know that I was on right track, but if you post a couple of sample images, you are talking about, that might help in providing you some more suggestions.

Comment: Here is one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/37//74438337_30052011063215_9539_3.jpg and a vertical one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/40//74273140_23052011090107_0806_3.jpg and a tricky one: http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/3/61/500396561_27052011171605_5877_3.jpg note that the last has partly white background, why i need to detect if the white-ish pixels goes all across the image width.

Comment: @esbenr, Well as far as I can tell. Hough transform is the candidate. Your lines are might end up with different lengths, and for this reason I will go with hough transform. As for the single loop approach, you will also need to tell what the line lengths would be, or which lines need to be joined in order to be considered as complete lines. You WILL find broken lines, i.e. lines that are not across the whole image.